# Rails, has_many, belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Schema:

```
  create_table "reports", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "apparatus"
    t.string   "capt"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "login",                     :limit => 40
    t.string   "name",                      :limit => 100, :default => ""
    t.string   "email",                     :limit => 100
    t.string   "crypted_password",          :limit => 40
    t.string   "salt",                      :limit => 40
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "remember_token",            :limit => 40
    t.datetime "remember_token_expires_at"
    t.string   "rank"
    t.integer  "shift"
    t.integer  "access"
  end
```

user model:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reports
#   bunch of other stuff thats not important
end
```

report model:

```
Class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

views/reports/index

```
<% @reports.each do |report| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= report.user_id %></td>  #     ****THIS IS THE LINE IN QUESTION****
    <td><%= report.apparatus %></td>
    <td><%= report.capt %></td>
    <td><%= report.body %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', report %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_report_path(report) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', report, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I would like to be able to display the name of the user that created the report. I was under the assumption that declaring the belongs_to and has_many associations would make this possible by writing report.user.name or something like that. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: ok, the problem was i had one tupple in my table that didn't have a user id. so it was getting hung up trying to find the name method on nil. I'm an ass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm 99% sure it's because one or more of your reports do not have an associated user. Try

```
<%= report.user.name rescue "none" %>
```

When there is no value in user_id field on a report then `report.user` will return nil. So `report.user.name` would be like calling `nil.name`, which raises an error.

UPDATE: here's a better way:

```
<%= report.user.try(:name) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
<%= report.user.name %>
```

But for efficiency, in your controller you can do a join to get the users name in the same query used to fetch @reports.

This query might look something like:

```
@reports = Report.select("reports.id as id, reports.apparatus as apparatus, reports.capt as capt, reports.body as body, users.name as user_name").joins("LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `reports`.`user_id`")
```

Then your output would look like:

```
<%= report.user_name %>
```

Comment: <%= report.user.name %> has not been working.
it gives "undefined method 'name'"

Comment: ok, the problem was i had one tupple in my table that didn't have a user id. so it was getting hung up trying to find the name method on nil. I'm an ass.

Comment: i'm a little late but glad you figured it out!